# Connect to Oracle Database from ubuntu

Tags: c++, oracle, ubuntu

I want to connect to an Oracle DB in a local network in Ubuntu using C++. As I've known so far it could be done through instant client library. But I didn't managed to connect.

I've tried other libraries such as soci, ODBC .., but they fail too.

I can connect to this Database using Oracle SQL developer GUI and there's not any problem. but using other libraries I face many different errors. I list some of them for you.

Using InstantClientLibrary12

```
user="XYZ";
pass="XYZ";
db="mdw.dbs.sharif.edu:1521";
Environment * env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT)
Connection * conn = env->createconnection(user,pass,db); //here it gives error
```

gives this error:

```
     Error: ORA-12163 - TNS:connect descriptor is too long
```

Using Soci Library

```
      session sql(soci::oracle,"service=mdw.dbs.sharif.edu:1521 user=XYZ pass=XYZ");
```

this gives this error

```
      ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

is these errors because of not officially supporting Ubuntu by Oracle ? has anyone successfully connected to Oracle DB in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to development. You have a configuration problem on tnsnames.ora file of your oracle client. You should reconfigure it on this structure:

```
<addressname> =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = <hostname>)(Port = <port>))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = <service_name>)
 )
)
```

Probably you forgot to specify the **SERVICE_NAME** on your file. Remember the tnsnames.ora file is on your /network/admin directory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Oscar, I didn't have this /network/admin in my system so searched in the Internet and realized that I need to have a complete installation of Oracle for this one ! what should I do ? I just need the Oracle driver to connect to a database , I don't want to install the whole oracle package. Is it possible  without having to install the Oracle Package ?

Comment: the network/admin dir is located where you installed oracle package. You can install only "instantclient" which is the lighter of all of them to do this but of course you must install an orackle package as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the SID/Service name in Soci example:

```
  session sql(soci::oracle,"service=mdw.dbs.sharif.edu:1521 user=XYZ pass=XYZ");
```

Try this (change MYSID with yours):

```
  session sql(soci::oracle,"service=mdw.dbs.sharif.edu:1521/MYSID user=XYZ pass=XYZ");
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it gives the "ORA-24454 client host name is not set" error message

Comment: Does "mdw.dbs.sharif.edu" resolve on that machine? Try pinging it.